# post querystring to mysql via php as opposed to placing the link in address bar

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to create a link in php, and submit that link, so that it will post the data contained therein to my mysql DB.

if i paste this link into my address bar, and press enter, i will be able to add a record to the DB, no matter from what website or browser:

```
http://mysite.com/data.php?first=bob&last=smith
```

data.php looks like this:

```
<? 
include("dbinfo.inc.php");

$first = $_GET['first'];
$last = $_GET['last'];

$query = "INSERT INTO db1 (first,last) VALUES ('$first','$last')";
mysql_query($query);

mysql_close();
?>
```

but what i want to do is on another site build the string, generate the link and send it through as if it were pasted into the address bar:

for example, lets say on website B i have this code for send.php:

```
<?
include('http://mysite.com/data.php?first=bob&last=smith');
?>
```

but that produces an error

then i tried:

```
<?
$url = 'http://mysite.com/data.php?first=bob&last=smith';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

but that doesn't post to the DB.

so, if i place the link directly in the browser address bar it *will* post to the DB, but i want to create php code, to generate the link and post the data as if it *were* pasted into the address bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
<?
$url = 'http://mysite.com/data.php?first=bob&last=smith';    

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
//echo $result;

curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file is written incorrectly. The variables don't match the query and you're not escaping them. I also used `mysqli` since `mysql` is depreciated. Keep in mind this isn't a good way to do it but I'll answer the question anyways.

```
include("dbinfo.inc.php");

$first= mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['first']);
$last = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['last']);

$query = "INSERT INTO db1 (first,last) VALUES ('$first','$last')";
mysqli_query($connection, $query);

mysqli_close();
```

Comment: In mysqli you pass the connection resource first. If you use the mysqli object instead you don't need to pass it.